# Scientific discoveries that were made "late"

Tags: discoveries, reference-request, examples

I'd like to ask a similar question from [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/699002) for the natural sciences (physics, chemistry, biology and allied disciplines).

What are examples of scientific results that were discovered surprisingly late in history? For instance, a paper where all the technology has been available for years, and the theoretical underpinnings necessary are not recent, so in principle the same research could have been conceived and published years ago.

I am particularly interested in **actual publications** in peer-reviewed journals.

By way of example, I think [Gibson assembly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibson_assembly) would be a good one: It is a simple modification of the standard PCR technique invented in the 70s. I imagine by the end of the 80s polymerases and buffers had been developed to the point that they could handle a simple Gibson assembly, and sequencing to confirm integrity of the product (or alternatively screening a library of products until a correct one is found) would also have been feasible. Whether the scientific community at large would have been more or less receptive to this idea at the time is another matter -- and something I specifically want to disregard for this question (ie. being "late" means late in terms of only technology and theory, not politics, funding and similar non-scientific prerequisites of scientific research).

Comment: To clarify the scope, you are interested in recent results, say in the last 100 years (peer review was rare before 1900, and only became common in 1950s http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_review#History), and reference to technology suggests "inventions" rather than theoretical or empirical discoveries, is that correct?

Comment: @Conifold Maybe it will be clearer if I ask like this: "What paper published in prestigious journals like *Nature*, *Science* and *PNAS* could have been published earlier (based on the theory and technology it builds on)?" I am not interested in inventions (unless they were published in prestigious peer-reviewed journals). I am interested in theoretical or empirical discoveries.

Answer (score 5):

More of an engineering feat, but I'd go for the Steam Engine (or at least a Segner Wheel), the basics had been there for about 1500 years (The use of compressed air in pumps, the idea that boiling water produces steam) and had been been used for sort of toys/novelties but the jump to powering machinery wasn't made.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeolipile

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segner_wheel

Answer (score 2):

One "late" contribution might be the discovery in the late 20th c that Rome's *Pantheon*, built in the 2nd c AD, was not "replicable" using modern technology and construction principles without the aid of a computer. In other words, the intricacies of design and materials that went into the Pantheon's construction were so rigorously conceived that our civilization's advanced machinery could not emulate the Romans' skill without the invention and addition of computer-aided design.

*On the Structure of the Roman Pantheon*
Robert Mark and Paul Hutchinson
*The Art Bulletin*
Vol. 68, No. 1 (Mar., 1986), pp. 24-34

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pantheon,_Rome

This video does much to explain just how remarkable the construction and design of the Pantheon was...and still is, "even for modern times."

*Pantheon: Ancient High Technology on the Next Level*

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYgne_mxjUs

Comment: I don't have access to the paper, but do the authors actually say this or is it your interpretation?

Comment: @Javier Does it matter?

Comment: MikeHunter - This could be an excellent answer, but @Javier's point does matter.

Comment: @HDE226868  Please clarify for me why the difference an interpretation vs a published opinion matters. It's still not clear to me that it does.

Comment: @MikeHunter You're citing an excellent source; Javier's trying to understand if what you say is purely what the source's information is or your interpretation of the source. Citing a source isn't good if what you say isn't at all what the source says.

Comment: @HDE226868  I don't agree that interpreting a source is weaker than what the source says. That said, my interpretation is supported by this source but the explicit statement is not in this source. Regardless, the statement stands.

Comment: @MikeHunter Hey, I just want to make sure I understand things! Don't worry; I'm not saying that your interpretation is worse than the source's. Thank you, though, for clarifying. I appreciate it.

Comment: In fact there **is** a difference between your interpretation and what the source says. The paper was (supposedly) written by specialists in the matter, while you may not be one, so you cannot evaluate the results in the same way they do. Let me give you an example: misinterpretations of quantum mechanics have led to copious amounts of pseudoscience.
$${}$$
Coming back to the present case, I don't think computers are **needed** to replicate the Pantheon. It would be hard to do it? most likely. Would it have been possible to replicate it decades or centuries ago? sure.

Comment: You are correct that I'm not a specialist in the matter. Are you? As it stands, your statement is just your opinion, nothing more nor less. You have offered nothing in the way of evidence to support your assertion. My statement stands, regardless of whether or not the citation backs it up. That said, I have absolutely no interest in going to war with you over this "matter." If I can find a better reference that explicitly documents my statement, I will share it. In the absence of that, the statement stands.

Comment: As you say I'm far from being an expert in the matter, I just asked the most natural question given the nature of the answer. In fact, when you say "My statement stands, regardless of whether or not the citation backs it up." seems like "your statement is just your opinion, nothing more nor less." I couldn't have said it better. This kind of situations are what the voting system is for, the community will decide for itself.

Comment: @javier  I did my best to find documentation for something I knew to be accurate based on an unpublished source. Otherwise, the absence of an explicit citation is the only thing missing from my statement. If and when I am able to track the reference down, I will provide it. I'm not in a hurry. The fact is and as you note, being a "non-expert," it's not something I could have come up with on my own. It came from someone who knows a lot more than either you or I. Your conjecture, on the other hand, was easily arrived at -- anybody desiring to contradict my statement could utter it.

Comment: @MikeHunter Note that voting behavior is an entirely personal choice for which no (rational or otherwise) justification needs to be provided. The same does not hold true for flagging: The comments pointing out a serious (potential) problem with your answer did not overstep any line in terms of politeness, as far as I could see. When you flag something, it requires a moderator to spend time (in this case, *waste* time) on it. Please, do not abuse the ability to flag. I've deleted a few *really* non-constructive comments towards the end of your and Javier's conversation.

Comment: @Danu  Your perception that both Javier and I were becoming a tad fractious is accurate. I'm not sure the mano a mano warranted deletion, but that's a matter of opinion. The key point is that the differences between Javier and I were substantial: in his view, my interpretation of an article's content did not sufficiently motivate my claims and, in my view, I could not have gotten to my statement without it's grounding in reality. His position is a matter more of pique than of anything else whereas my statement only needs a citation to back it up. My statement stands.

Comment: I don't think that qualifies as late discovery, I think it qualifies as a forgotten technology. The Romans knew how to make hydraulic cement, which was not rediscovered until the late 1800s. We've lost a lot of the old technological skills because the elites of the eras did not think them worthy of recording.

Comment: We often have to to use computers to produce precise measurements and calculations be because we use precision manufactured linear measuring tools but up to 150 years ago, most precision measurement was done with dividers and transfers of angles. All precision work used virtually no numerical information at all, just mechanically transferred ratios of angles. Probably if you dragged a stone mason from the back beyond of tibet or somewhere where they still use pre-industrial methods, he could figure out how the Romans built the parthenon without computers.

Comment: Paper on the Pantheon here: https://booksc.org/book/31971923/cf23f2

Answer (score -1):

Don't have recent peer reviewed examples but just for interest there are some odd detours in the history of science.

In biology a famous example is Mendelian genetics which was made in the mid-1800s but utterly unrecognized at the time only to be independently rediscovered by two different researchers circa 1904. It's possible a lot political ugliness of the 20th century might have been blunted if population genetics and thus synthetic Darwinism had got an earlier start.

I've read that relativity could have been deduced from Maxwells equations on electromagnetism but I don't have the source off the top of my head.

The big bang is innate in Newtonian physics. When ask why the universe didn't collapse as his models predicted, Newton said god had made the universe balanced precisely to be stable.

The big bang was evident in Hubble's work, but speculation on it was ignored until Bell labs stumbled into the cosmic background radiation.

Edison, Tesla and other electrical inventors of their day were repeatedly told by scientist that many of the inventions would not work because the primary scientific model for electricity, especially in plasma like Edison and Cathode ray tubes, was seriously flawed. Not sure if that counts as late discovery, as the inventors made things thought impossible which sent scientist scrambling.

Comment: I'm curious. How would an earlier start to "synthetic Darwinism" have blunted "a lot political ugliness of the 20th century"?

Comment: A lot of the statements in this answer sound to me like they're oversimplified or based on an incorrect understanding of historical reality. Tesla was in many ways a charlatan, and many of his ideas *were* impractical. It's a vast oversimplification to say that "the big bang is innate in Newtonian physics." Newtonian physics has trouble formulating a static, stable model of the cosmos. That's very different from saying that people in Newton's era could have inferred the existence of a big bang. Re Hubble, you simply have the sequence of events wrong. Le Maitre was 1927.